# Text exceeds the circle boundry in html

Tags: html, css

I am making a circle with text in it, but the problem is when i write some text it exceeds the circle boundry. Please have a look at this pic:

[image]

Following is my code

```html
 <svg  width="200" height="200" style = "border-style: solid; border-color: #696969;border-radius:50%;border-width: 8px;">
    
    <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="white"   />
    
    <text padding-right= "80px" x="30%" y="30%" text-align= "center"  font-size="20px" font-family="Arial" dy=".3em">Place the text here</text>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Its depend on your X and Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change x and y percentage value in `<text/>` it will works

```html
<svg  width="200" height="200" style = "border-style: solid; border-color: #696969;border-radius:50%;border-width: 8px;">

<circle cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="white"   />

<text padding-right= "80px" x="10%" y="35%" text-align= "center"  font-size="20px" font-family="Arial" dy=".3em">
 <tspan x="10%" dy=".6em">Place the text here</tspan>
 <tspan x="10%" dy="1.1em">Place the text here</tspan>
  <tspan x="10%" dy="1.1em">Place the text here</tspan>
</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It still exceeds the body if I add more text. I wanted it to be divided into lines if it exceeds into more text. thank you

Comment: for extra text you have to use  `<tspan>` @MuhammadUsman check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Change your X and Y by `10%` and `45%` and you can also play with this values

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" style="border-style: solid; border-color: #696969; border-radius:50%; border-width: 8px;">
    <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="white">
    <text padding-right="80px" x="10%" y="45%" text-align="center" font-size="20px" font-family="Arial" dy=".3em">Place the text here</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It still exceeds the body if I add more text. I wanted it to be divided into lines if it exceeds into more text. thank yo